# Primefaces <p:collector> adding only one row

Tags: primefaces, collect

I am trying to use p:collector to collect list of state objects. The problem is that only one row gets added to the stateList. After adding one row, when I click the commandButton, nothing gets added to the stateList. Here is my code. It seems I am missing out something obvious.

JSF page
  Code:
                        
                        >" action="#{bulkStateBean.reInit}" update="f:statePanel" >

Backing Bean (bulkStateBean)
  Code:
    private List stateList = new ArrayList();
    private State state = new State();

```
public String reInit() {
    state = new State();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change scope of the bean to **"session"** in `Faces-config.xml-> Managed Beans`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. The entity class State has the @override methods, which were generated while creating new entity through create new entity wizard. remove all the overridden methods from the entity and save it. Thats all. Now it will work. It worked for me.